# How can we stop and resume subscribing to an Observable method while communicating from a routed to a non-routed component

Tags: angular

I had to make skip level components talk to each other via events. So, I created a service and injected it in all parties interested in communicating. I created a subject in the service and published a value to it from my GrandChildComponent and allowed the Component to subscribe to this Subject inside the constructor and be notified.
Now, my GrandChildComponent is a non-routed dialog/popup. So, when I try to navigate to my GrandChildComponent from Component ngDestroy doesn,t get called.

I manually tried to use the unsubscribe() method, as and when I open my dialog GrandChildComponent. But I cannot subscribe back to the Subject on returning from my GrandChildComponent to the Component, as the constructor method does not get invoked. How do I deal with this unsubscribe and subscribe problem, which is important to prevent memory leaks.

`

```
/**
*Service(ABCService) Component:
*/
emitEvent(eventName: string, event: any) {
 this.subject.next(
  {
   eventName: eventName,
   event: event
  }
 );
}

getEvent(): Observable<any> {
 return this.subject.asObservable();
}

/**
*Parent Component:
*/

subs: Subscription
constructor(private abcService: ABCService){
 this.subs = this.abcService.getEvent().subscribe( ev => {
  if(ev.eventName == "xyz") {
   if(ev.event == "abc") {
    //hide the dialog
    this.ngOnInit();
   }
  }
 });
}

/**
*Child(Dialog) Component:
*/

constructor(private abcService: ABCService){}
close() {
 this.abcService.emitEvent("xyz", "abc");
}
```

Comment: can you provide some code to show what you mean? Unsubscribing is probably not necessary as long as the component exists. Unless you're somehow subscribing again to the observable after the dialog closes - but then I'd say the re-subscription is the problem.

Comment: Updated the post with code snippets.

Comment: Thank you for adding the sample code. So... I'm probably missing something but I don't see a problem. The Parent just keeps listening to events from the service until it gets destroyed (you do want to unsubscribe in the ngOnDestroy). But until the parent is actually destroyed, it keeps listening as intended - so why unsubscribe before that?

Some opinionated stuff:
- I'd avoid calling a function that's also an ng hook (ngOnInit call)
- for components it's considered good style to move logic from the constructor to the ngOnInit

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe when the component is created and unsubscribe when it is destroyed. If it is a component that needs to be destroyed when it's hidden (e.g. popup), you could use `ngIf` on the popup component to create and destroy it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I believe, the problem is something else. It's not about the popup subscribing an event or destroying as and when created, but about the component which is calling the popup, re-subscribing everytime I close the popup. I have updated the post with my code snippets for better understanding. Hope it helps.